# Query appears to work in console but cannot get data in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use this query

pages_controller.rb

```
# GET /pages/1
# GET /pages/1.json
def show
  @page = Page.where('category_title = ?', params[:category_title]).where('slug = ?', params[:slug])
end
```

routes.rb

```
match ':category_title/:slug', :via => 'get', :controller => :pages, :action => :show
```

I get an error in the view of "undefined method' for the properties of that page (id, slug, etc.). The query looks right to me in the console but when the page loads it is not actually getting any data.

[image]

If I print out a count it comes back as 1, which is correct.

[image]

I have looked at a few posts about creating named routes and thought I had it, but clearly I am missing something.

Any help with what part of this I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was add ".first" to the query

```
@page = Page.where('category_title = ?', params[:category_title]).where('slug = ?', params[:slug]).first
```

worked